# Suexec, group-writeable files

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, cgi, suexec

I am running an Apache server with Suexec. However, I get an internal server error if I try to execute a CGI script that is group-writeable (if I chmod g-w , the script runs fine)

However, I *want* the file to be group-writeable. SuPHP has a config option that allows me to do this, but I can't find the analogous option for Suexec. How can I run CGI scripts that are g+w?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an explicit check which [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html#model) does, and can only be removed by modifying the source code (which is not recommended).

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Too bad suEXEC cannot run cgi files with any permission other than 755 (assuming this is the case).