# suexec executes world writable php files and files owned by root. why?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, suexec

I've configured my server to use suexec for php this weekend. Now I've recognized that suexec also serves files owned by root or that are world writable. But this seems to me not like the standard behavior documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html#model).

So why does suexec work with this files?

I use Debian 6 Squeeze stable.

It's a bit like the opposite of [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/390484/suexec-group-writeable-files).